# SQL - NOW() + 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't find solution, I'm trying to take in my database date of event that are 10 days after now.

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM XXX.Vente WHERE date > (now()+40);
```

and :

```
SELECT * FROM LeVigneau.Vente WHERE date > now()+INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

But it doesn't work. 
Du you have an idea ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: should it be exactly 10 days? or more?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use backticks on date, that because `DATE` is [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and `DATE_ADD` function in following:

**Syntax**

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM LeVigneau.Vente WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Also use `>=` or `=`, It depends on what exactly do you need, to get records only for 10th day from now or from 10 days and later.

Comment: I would also like to know this, it seems someone is just downvoting all of the answers on this question

Comment: Thanks guys, It works well.
No idea why one person downvoting all your answers

Comment: @RomainCaron your welcome and do not forget to accept correct answer for future users.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas yes sure ;)

Comment: No need to read your answer to suggest simple thing like this :)

Answer (score 2):

For exactly 10 days:

```
SELECT * FROM LeVigneau.Vente WHERE `date` = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

All other solution give more then 10 days, not exactly 10 days.

for 10 days or more:

```
SELECT * FROM LeVigneau.Vente WHERE `date` >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM LeVigneau.Vente WHERE date > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```